# Subroutine vs functions in python

Tags: python, function, subroutine

I was reading about a coroutine [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine). Official docs say

> Coroutines are a more generalized form of subroutines. Subroutines are
> entered at one point and exited at another point. Coroutines can be
> entered, exited, and resumed at many different points.

But, no where in the [Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#glossary) a subroutine is defined. From my understanding, in Python, there's no difference between a function and a subroutine. But, I could not find this exactly in official documentation. So, can anyone confirm this? If they are indeed different, I want to know how?

Comment: A coroutine is a function that you can `yield` and `resume` it later. By yielding, I mean like pausing it. Imagine being able to pause the function when it reaches a certain line of code. Then, outside that function, you can resume the function from that point on. That's what a coroutine is.

Comment: A normal function cannot be yielded / paused. It can only be return a value. If you attempt to call the function once again, it will not be resumed from the point it was returned. It will start from the beggining until it returns.

Comment: About using coroutines in python, you can use the module `asyncio`. For more information, just search about this module on your browser.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.  Subroutine and function in this context are the same.  In general a subroutine could be more broadly defined than just functions though

Comment: @CarlHR and Alexander, thanks.